# format iso date from sql database and return to blade

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, laravel-blade

SQL stores date as iso y-m-d

With:

```
Carbon\Carbon::parse($data[0]->date)->format('j F Y');
```

I can format the date to -> in the format  `7 July 2018`

However, i want to edit each date in the entire collection obtained

from         `$data= Data::where('id',$id)->get();`

This will then be saved to the collection and showed in blade. Would you use a for loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel's query builders always return a collection when you use get().

Laravel provides a lot of collection methods you can make use of on these.  A good method for transforming data is map.

```
$data = $data->map(function($item) {
    // Do any transformation to $item and return it
    $item->date = Carbon::parse($item->date)->format('j F Y');
    return $item;
});
```

Of course, with programming, there are often multiple ways to accomplish the same task.  A simple foreach loop would do as well:

```
foreach($data as $item) {
    $item->date = Carbon::parse($item->date)->format('j F Y');
}
```

This works well with objects since objects are always passed by reference.  So you can make changes to the object and it will persist in the original 
collection.

Comment: youre the best :)